# .NET SOA commercial recommendation

Tags: .net, caching, message-queue, soa

I am looking for a .NET middleware system that covers message queueing, distributed caches, failover/redundancy. I'd prefer to look at a standards based commercial solution of some kind.

What would you recommend? Anything available which from a company point of view has stood the test of time, which is highly likely to stay in business?

One aspect that is important is that we want something that has good management/monitoring tools. I guess the Java world has had a lot of these for many years now however nothing seems to leap out at me from the .NET world.

Answer (score 0):

I think Microsoft BizTalk is pretty close to what you're looking for. It supports, queueing, caches, failover support and has nice monitoring/managment tools. You can even write code for using .NET.

http://www.microsoft.com/biztalk/en/us/default.aspx

An alternative may be coming in the form of Dublin, but that may not be released for a while.

http://www.microsoft.com/net/Dublin.aspx